# JavaFX SplitPane dynamically resize children

Tags: javafx, resize, pane

I have a `SplitPane` and within it two items which are `VBox` and `ScrollPane`. In the `VBox` I have some `TitledPane` children that can be collapsed and therefore minimize the `VBox` height, or this is what I thought will happen. But the issue is that only the inner elements of the `VBox` are being shrunk inside it and the actual `VBox` child height stays the same.

I want the `VBox` to dynamically change in height and the divider of the `SplitPane` to automatically fill the gap of the shrunk `VBox` so that the `ScrollPane` will fill that gap.

```
<SplitPane fx:id="infoSplitPane" orientation="VERTICAL" dividerPositions="0.35">
    <items>
        <VBox fx:id="campaignInfoVBox" spacing="10" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
                <Label text="Campaign Information" style="-fx-font-size: 120%" />                                         
                <SplitPane fx:id="campaignInfoSplitPane" orientation="VERTICAL">
                    <items>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="campaignTestsFlow" text="Campaign Tests Flow">
                            <TableView fx:id="testCasesTableView" minHeight="52" maxHeight="Infinity" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                <columnResizePolicy>
                                    <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                </columnResizePolicy>
                            </TableView>
                        </TitledPane>
                        <TitledPane fx:id="campaignActionsInfo" text="Campaign Actions Information">
                            <SplitPane fx:id="campaignTablesSplitPane" orientation="VERTICAL" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                <items>
                                    <RunnerActionsTreeTableView fx:id="campaignSetupTable" name="Campaign Setup" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                    <RunnerActionsTreeTableView fx:id="campaignTearDownTable" name="Campaign Tear Down" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                </items>
                            </SplitPane>
                        </TitledPane>
                    </items>
                </SplitPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="testInfoScrollPane" fitToWidth="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <content>
                <VBox spacing="0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <GridPane hgap="5.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" vgap="5.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                        <children>                                                                                    
                            <VBox fx:id="titledPaneVbox"  GridPane.rowIndex="13" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
                                <TitledPane fx:id="variablesTitlePane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Variables Information" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" >
                                    <content>
                                        <TableView fx:id="variablesTable" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"  GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS"  />
                                    </content>
                                </TitledPane>
                                <TitledPane fx:id="eventsTitlePane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Events Information" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"  GridPane.columnSpan="2">
                                    <content>
                                        <TableView fx:id="eventsTable" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
                                    </content>
                                </TitledPane>
                            </VBox>
                            <Button fx:id="testCaseDirButton" text="Logs Folder" maxWidth="Infinity" GridPane.rowIndex="14" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
                        </children>
                    </GridPane>
                </VBox>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </items>
</SplitPane>
```

So basically what I need it the `testInfoScrollPane` to adjust itself to `campaignInfoVBox` bottom margin when it is being shrunk automatically when its `TitledPane` children are collapsing.

Comment: The [`SplitPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) API prompts me to ask if `testInfoScrollPane` "needs to be placed inside a layout container."

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set the `maxHeight` attribute of `VBox` to the prefHeight of its contents. That way, the `VBox` can never grow beyond the size of its contents.

You can try the below code:

If in java code:

```
campaignInfoVBox.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

If in FXML code:

```
<VBox fx:id="campaignInfoVBox" spacing="10" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" maxHeight="-Infinity">
```

Below is a quick demo that demonstrates the fix:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SplitPaneFitContentDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane content = new StackPane();
        content.setMinSize(200, 800);
        content.setStyle("-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, red);");
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(content);

        VBox pane = new VBox();
        // Try setting the below one. In FXML, for the VBox it should have the attribute maxHeight="-Infinity"
        pane.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            VBox tpContent = new VBox(10, new Button("Button A" + i), new Button("Button B" + i));
            TitledPane tp = new TitledPane("Title " + i, tpContent);
            tp.setMaxHeight(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
            VBox.setVgrow(tp, Priority.ALWAYS);
            pane.getChildren().add(tp);
        }

        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(pane, scrollPane);
        splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.35);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(splitPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("SplitPane");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
When applied the attribute in the provided FXML, this is how it works.

[image]

Comment: Can you still drag the split-pane's divider around? I had a similar solution in a now-deleted answer, but then realized setting the `VBox`'s max height this way prevented the divider from resizing it when the user whished to do so.

Comment: If both the TitledPanes are collapsed, I really don't see the need to drag the divider to view the empty space. And that is how JavaFX is also working. Having said that, if atleast one of the TitledPane is expanded, it allows to drag the divider to the max possible height of the Titledpane content. Which is also quite acceptable. 
If the user wants both the features, like the divider should automatically adjust and still needs to be draggable to see the empty space, then I believe we need the more specific logic for that behaviour.

Comment: I updated the demo gif for the behaviour I mentioned above.

Comment: Interesting. My code doesn't let the user drag the divider _at all_. After trying your code, I find it suffers from the same problem. Yet if I replace the `Button`s in your code, or the `Label` in my code, with `TableView`(s), then the divider can be dragged, as long as at least one `TitledPane` is expanded.

Comment: @Slaw i think the reason for button as not stretchable because of its computed height. If you set the Button/Label's setMaxHeight(Double.Infinity), then it will allow to drag. Though i have not tested it yet.

Comment: Tried that; didn't work. Looking at the source code, I think it has to do with how the various controls compute their _preferred_ height. The default `Label` and `Button` skins compute their respective preferred heights based on their actual content. But a `TableView` just says its preferred height is `400`. And in fact, it looks like I can't drag the divider any further after the `TableView` reaches that height (though I can drag it the other way, shrinking the table). But maybe that's the behavior the OP wants, not sure.